# Hadoop - Hawq - Add new segment

Tags: hadoop, hawq

I installed hawq on Hadoop using ambari.
in the installation step , I chose the Hawq master host with 2 segments , and all was working fine.
then later,  I added a new hawq segment using ambari , installation process went smoothly with no errors.
but i realized that the new segment was not actually added to the hawq cluster and /data/hawq/segments directory is empty in this new node.

Am I missing any step to add the new segment to hawq cluster ?

any help or hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Can you clarify your HAWQ version?
2. I assume you mean adding a
   new HAWQ "node" not "segment"? HAWQ 1.x cannot dynamically
   add/remove segment number, which is pre-determined through HAWQ
   initialization
3. check: http://pivotalhd-210.docs.pivotal.io/doc/2010/ExpandingtheHAWQSystem.html it's a little bit old doc but you can cross-ref to see if this is what you intend to do.

Comment: i managed to solve the issue using gpexpand tool , thanks for your answer.